# Is there a module for Image Sitemaps?

Tags: 6, media, xml-sitemap

I have been looking to expose the images hosted on my site to Google Images search. I was wondering is there is a Drupal 6 module to do that? I am on Pressflow 6.

I can see such modules available for Drupal 7 (see below). http://drupal.org/project/google_image_sitemap 
AND
http://drupal.org/node/451234

Answer (score 0):

The module http://drupal.org/project/google_image_sitemap has a d6 version but it was released after the d7 version :)